# Genitivus Partitivus

Tags: conjugation

> Es gab ganz viele solcher Gesetze, die nur ein Ziel hatten: die jüdischen Menschen zu quälen. Und Hitlers Hass übertrug sich auf viele Menschen im damaligen Deutschen Reich. Sie glaubten den Worten Hitlers und taten das, was der von ihnen verlangten. So behandelten sie Juden schlecht und wollten nichts mehr mit ihnen zutun haben. Sie beschmierten die Häuser, in denen Juden lebten und beschimpften sie auf der Straße. Später verrieten manche der Polizei sogar, wo sich Juden versteckt hielten, damit die sie verhaften konnte.

Why does "Gesetze" get "solcher" instead of "solche" in the first sentence and is there anything wrong with "was der von ihnen verlangten"? Perhaps it should have been either "der" (i.e. Hitler) "verlangt" or "die" (i.e. the words) "verlangten".

Source: https://www.zdf.de/kinder/logo/die-nationalsozialisten-und-der-holocaust-100.html

Comment: It must be _was der von ihnen verlangte_ - probably a typo. For the grammatical question, see my answer.

Comment: The title would be appropiate for a history forum or whatever other topic, but not for grammar.

Comment: This text has multiple separate smaller issues with grammar, orthography and style that have nothing to do with each other. I think this question is too unfocused for this kind of forum.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *Genitivus Partitivus*, a genitive expressing that one thing is a part of some other thing. In this case, it could be translated as "Many of such laws." *viele*, *einige*, *manche* are signal words for this genitive.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is considered elevated and/or outdated